# how to set current date as default value in a text field in jsp

Tags: jsp, struts, struts-1

I want to set `current date` as default value in a `text` field in `jsp`

without using any `scriptlets` or **javascript** or **java code**

any **struts1.2** tags available for this? or any other way

Comment: Were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Struts 1.x documentation](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html), you should use [`<bean:write>`](http://struts.apache.org/development/1.x/struts-taglib/tlddoc/bean/write.html) tag:

```
<bean:write name="yourBean" format="MM-dd-yyyy" property="date" />
```

Alternatively, you could use [JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/) [`<fmt:formatDate>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/formatDate.html) tag:

```
<fmt:formatDate value="${yourBean.date}" pattern="MM-dd-yyyy" />
```

Or, you may wish to upgrade to [Struts 2](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/tag-reference.html) and use [`<s:date>`](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.0.x/docs/date.html) tag:

```
<s:date name="date" format="MM-dd-yyyy" />
```

Of course, JavaScript `var date = new Date()` and Java `<c:set var="date" value="<%=new java.util.Date()%>" />` in scriptlet are always there as well.